# Rails browser gem is returing 'generic' for all reported information

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am developing an application in rails 5. The application is up and running in both development and production environments. I am using the browser gem to obtain platform, browser, and device specific information. However, it is only returning 'generic' for all browser, platform, and device information. If I use the request operation, i.e. - `request.env['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` or `request.remote_ip`. I get the expected information (yes, I know the IP information is not returned via browser. I included it just to 'show' the browser and connection information is available). I have run bundle update to ensure that the latest version of the browser and other gem(s) are installed.

I have the browser gem declared in Gemfile:

```
gem 'browser', require: 'browser/browser'
```

Per the [browser README.md](https://github.com/fnando/browser) to avoid needing to make a declaration in a controller.

The following is the code snippet for how browser is being used (also per the [browser README.md](https://github.com/fnando/browser)). connection is an object within my application for recording the obtained browser information.

```
    browser = Browser.new("Some User Agent", accept_language: "en-us")

    connection.browser_name = browser.name
    connection.browser_full_version = browser.full_version
    connection.browser_device_name = browser.device.name
    connection.browser_platform_name = browser.platform.name
    connection.browser_platform_version = browser.platform.version
```

I'm using nginx and puma for both production and development. The behavior is identical whether it is the production or development environment. Also, in development whether I use nginx or bypass and go directly to puma 'generic' is the reported information.

The application is using HTTP 1.1 and `<!DOCTYPE html>` is declared for the view(s).

The following is the output obtained from:

`puts request.env['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.12; rv:53.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/53.0
```

`puts browser`

```
unknown generic generic0 other
```

`puts browser.name`

```
Generic Browser
```

`puts browser.inspect`

```
#<Browser::Generic:0x007fe24aa41710 @ua="Some User Agent", @accept_language=[#<Browser::AcceptLanguage:0x007fe24aa415d0 @part="en-us", @quality=1.0>], @platform=#<Browser::Platform:0x007fe24aa33d90 @ua="Some User Agent", @subject=#<Browser::Platform::Other:0x007fe24aa33b88 @ua="Some User Agent">>, @device=#<Browser::Device:0x007fe24aa41008 @ua="Some User Agent", @subject=#<Browser::Device::Unknown:0x007fe24aa40d38 @ua="Some User Agent">, @platform=#<Browser::Platform:0x007fe24aa32da0 @ua="Some User Agent", @subject=#<Browser::Platform::Other:0x007fe24aa32b98 @ua="Some User Agent">>>>
```

`puts browser.to_yaml`

```
--- !ruby/object:Browser::Generic
ua: Some User Agent
accept_language:
- !ruby/object:Browser::AcceptLanguage
  part: en-us
  quality: 1.0
platform: !ruby/object:Browser::Platform
  ua: Some User Agent
  subject: !ruby/object:Browser::Platform::Other
    ua: Some User Agent
device: !ruby/object:Browser::Device
  ua: Some User Agent
  subject: !ruby/object:Browser::Device::Unknown
    ua: Some User Agent
platform: !ruby/object:Browser::Platform
  ua: Some User Agent
  subject: !ruby/object:Browser::Platform::Other
    ua: Some User Agent

--- !ruby/object:Browser::Platform
ua: Some User Agent
```

Comment: Could you show the code that uses the `browser` gem to obtain the info?

Comment: I have added the requested information.

Answer (score 4):

It seems you're passing `"Some User Agent"` as the first argument. This is where `User-Agent` sent by the browser should be passed:

```
browser = Browser.new(request.headers['User-Agent'], accept_language: request.headers["Accept-Language"])
```

You also wrote:

> Per the browser README.md to avoid needing to make a declaration in a controller.

`README` says (emphasis mine):

> If you want to use Browser on your Rails app but don't want to **taint** your controller, use the following line on your Gemfile:

"Taint" means automatically adding methods to all controllers, not avoiding a declaration. If this is the intended behavior then feel free to leave the code as it is. However, if you'd like to have a `browser` method available in all controller actions without having to do extra setup then put:

```
gem 'browser'
```

in `Gemfile`. It should automatically include [`Browser::ActionController`](https://github.com/fnando/browser/blob/master/lib/browser/action_controller.rb) into the base controller with the `browser` method defined like this:

```
def browser
  @browser ||= Browser.new(
    request.headers["User-Agent"],
    accept_language: request.headers["Accept-Language"]
  )
end
```

Comment: Using request.xxx rather than the string worked, mostly; thank you. The browser fields now have the expected contents, except device, which is still unknown. However, changing Gemfile (from "gem browser, require browser/bowser" to "gem browser") didn't seem to have any effect. I appreciate the help; again thank you.

Comment: My pleasure! The effect of using `gem "browser"` in `Gemfile` should be that you won't need to do `browser = Browser.new ...` yourself. When it comes to device detection, I looked at [the device detection code](https://github.com/fnando/browser/tree/master/lib/browser/device) and it's detected based on `User-Agent`. If you post an example `User-Agent` that was passed to `Browser.new` I might be able to identify why the device is unknown.

Comment: My apologies; I'm not sure what you are asking with respect to the User-Agent. I thought the string returned by request.headers was the

Comment: This is the User-Agent string passed when using a Kindle-Fire `request.headers['User-Agent'] => Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.0.4; KFJWI Build/IMM76D) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Silk/57.2.2 like Chrome/57.0.2987.132 Safari/537.36`. I don't see a device in that string; however, this is the User-Agent string when using an LG phone - `Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1.1; LG-K330 Build/LMY47V) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.132 Mobile Safari/537.36`. Here I do see a device. But, the device is 'unknown' for both accesses.

Comment: I cannot get this working. Have you configured it on a before_filter action into the ApplicationController? Or where?